# specifying exponential families with matrices

Tags: distributions, matrix, exponential-family

I'm new to statistics, but I'm currently reading *Algebraic Statistics for Computational Biology*. In it, the authors state that we can define an exponential family with a $d \times m$ non-negative integer matrix, $A=(a_{ij})$, with the property that all column sums are equal. My question is why this assumption is necessary?

The full definition used in the book is:

> Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a non-negative integer $d \times m$ matrix with the property that all column sums are equal: 
>   $$ \sum_{i=1}^da_{i1}=\sum_{i=1}^da_{i2}=\ldots=\sum_{i=1}^da_{im}$$
>   The $j$-th column vector $a_j$ of the matrix $A$ represents the monomial$$ \theta^{a_j}=\prod_{i=1}^d{\theta_i}^{a_{ij}} \ \ \ \text{for } \ j=1,2 ,\ldots,n$$
>   Our assumption says that these monomials all have the same degree.
>   The toric model of $A$ is the image of the orthant $\Theta = \mathbb{R}^d_{>0}$ under the map$$
> \textbf{f} : \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m,\quad \theta\mapsto\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^m\theta^{a_j}}\cdot(\theta^{a_1}, \theta^{a_2},\ldots,\theta^{a_m})$$